Using Python Great Expectations and python-oracledb
I would like to set up an oracledb as a datasource but can't get the syntax. Is this even possible?
import oracledb
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import getpass

username = getpass.getuser()
userpwd = getpass.getpass()
dsn="my_server"
# connect to oracle database
connection=oracledb.connect(
     user=username,
     password=userpwd,
     dsn=dsn
)
# create engine
engine = create_engine('oracle+oracledb://', creator=lambda: connection)

This is successful for connecting and passing to, for example pandas.read_sql.
But I want to use gx:
import great_expectations as gx
context = gx.get_context()
context.sources.add...?

I tried to get a connection string
cp = oracledb.ConnectParams(user=username, password=userpwd,host=dsn)
conn_string = cp.get_connect_string()
datasource = context.sources.add_sql(
    name="my_datasource", connection_string=conn_string
)

But this dowsn't work

TestConnectionError: Attempt to connect to datasource failed with the
following error message: Unable to create a SQLAlchemy engine due to
the following exception: Could not parse SQLAlchemy URL from string
'(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=myserver)(PORT=1521)))'

Any ideas?

This creates a data source for me:
import getpass
import os
import oracledb
import great_expectations as gx

un = os.environ.get('PYTHON_USERNAME')
cs = os.environ.get('PYTHON_CONNECTSTRING')
pw = getpass.getpass(f'Enter password for {un}@{cs}: ')

# I use Easy Connect strings like "localhost/orclpdb1".  These two lines
# let me access the components individually
cp = oracledb.ConnectParams()
cp.parse_connect_string(cs)

connection_string = f'oracle+oracledb://{un}:{pw}@{cp.host}:{cp.port}/?service_name={cp.service_name}'

context = gx.get_context()

datasource = context.sources.add_sql(
    name="my_datasource", connection_string=connection_string
)

asset_name = "my_query_asset"
query = "select * from employees"

query_asset = datasource.add_query_asset(name=asset_name, query=query)

for i in query_asset:
    print(i)


Running it gives:
('name', 'my_query_asset')
('type', 'query')
('id', None)
('order_by', [])
('batch_metadata', {})
('splitter', None)
('query', 'select * from employees')

For information on connecting oracledb with SQLAlchemy, see Using SQLAlchemy 2.0 with python-oracledb for Oracle Database.

Hey this is great, thanks!
So in my case it worked
cp = oracledb.ConnectParams(user=username, password=userpwd,host=dsn)
and
connection_string = f'oracle+oracledb://{username}:{userpwd}@{cp.host}:{cp.port}'
I didn't need the service name.
